# Fill an oval every second

Tags: java, swing

I've got 8 ovals all set to the same colour. After a second I want the first oval to change colours and then after another second i want the first oval to go back to its original colour and then change the second ovals colour. I've drawn the circles and I've tried implementing a thread but i think it's not executing...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Circle extends JPanel implements Runnable
{

  Graphics g;

  Thread t = new Thread();

  int[][] fillCircles = new int[8][4];


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    this.g = g;
    super.paintComponent(this.g);

    this.g.setColor(new java.awt.Color(237, 54, 26));

    this.g.drawOval(300, 50, 100, 100);
    this.g.drawOval(450, 125, 100, 100);
    this.g.drawOval(500, 250, 100, 100);
    this.g.drawOval(425, 375, 100, 100);
    this.g.drawOval(300, 400, 100, 100);
    this.g.drawOval(175, 350, 100, 100);
    this.g.drawOval(125, 225, 100, 100);
    this.g.drawOval(175, 100, 100, 100);

    this.g.fillOval(300, 50, 100, 100);
    this.g.fillOval(450, 125, 100, 100);
    this.g.fillOval(500, 250, 100, 100);
    this.g.fillOval(425, 375, 100, 100);
    this.g.fillOval(300, 400, 100, 100);
    this.g.fillOval(175, 350, 100, 100);
    this.g.fillOval(125, 225, 100, 100);
    this.g.fillOval(175, 100, 100, 100);

    fillCircles[0][0] = 300;
    fillCircles[0][1] = 50;
    fillCircles[0][2] = 100;
    fillCircles[0][3] = 100;

    fillCircles[1][0] = 450;
    fillCircles[1][1] = 125;
    fillCircles[1][2] = 100;
    fillCircles[1][3] = 100;

    fillCircles[2][0] = 500;
    fillCircles[2][1] = 250;
    fillCircles[2][2] = 100;
    fillCircles[2][3] = 100;

    fillCircles[3][0] = 425;
    fillCircles[3][1] = 375;
    fillCircles[3][2] = 100;
    fillCircles[3][3] = 100;

    fillCircles[4][0] = 300;
    fillCircles[4][1] = 400;
    fillCircles[4][2] = 100;
    fillCircles[4][3] = 100;

    fillCircles[5][0] = 175;
    fillCircles[5][1] = 350;
    fillCircles[5][2] = 100;
    fillCircles[5][3] = 100;

    fillCircles[6][0] = 125;
    fillCircles[6][1] = 225;
    fillCircles[6][2] = 100;
    fillCircles[6][3] = 100;

    fillCircles[7][0] = 175;
    fillCircles[7][1] = 100;
    fillCircles[7][2] = 100;
    fillCircles[7][3] = 100;


}

Circle () {
    t.start();
}


public void run () {

    int circle = 0;

    try {
        for (;;) {

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            if (circle > 0) {
                this.g.setColor(new java.awt.Color(237, 54, 26));
                circle--;
                this.g.fillOval(fillCircles[circle][0], fillCircles[circle][1], fillCircles[circle][2], fillCircles[circle][2]);
                circle++;
            }
            this.g.setColor(Color.red);
            this.g.fillOval(fillCircles[circle][0], fillCircles[circle][1], fillCircles[circle][2], fillCircles[circle][2]);


            circle++;

            if (circle == 8) {
                circle = 0;
            }

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println ("Thread Interrupted");
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Circle c;

    JFrame application = new JFrame();

    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    application.add(c=new Circle());
    application.setSize(1200, 900);
    application.setVisible(true); 


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You're just instantiating a `Thread` without giving it a `Runnable`, so it's not running what you're intending.

```
Thread t = new Thread();
```

should be

```
Thread t = new Thread(this);
```

this because the `Circle` is `Runnable` and the `run()` method is in it.
Regarding color changing, I would give you an idea. 
When drawing the circles, check the current circle number/index against another variable which changes every second `colorChangeIndex`

```
if(circleIndex == colorChangeIndex){
  // another color
else
 //the default color
colorChangeIndex++; (modulo number of cricles to reset it)
```

Comment: check the current circle ... ---> I don't follow.

Answer (score 1):

The  basic structure of your code is wrong. Painting should only be done in the paintComponent() method. You should never reference the Graphics object in your thread.

So, instead what you might want to do is keep an ArrayList of "circle" objects. This custom object will contain the circle to be painted and its color. Then in the paintComponent() method you just iterate through the ArrayList and paint all the circles in the ArrayList. Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

> After a second I want the first oval to change colours and then after another second i want the first oval to go back to its original colour and then change the second ovals colour.

So now you need to use a `Swing Timer` to animate the painting. When the Timer fires you reset the Color of the appropriate circle and then just repaint the panel.